# Working on audio mixing application for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on creating a DJ mix app for Iphone in which a user can select two audio files and can select parts of the audio files to create a new audio files.
I was going through some libraries for audio mixing, I was going though Extended Audio Services libraries in Iphone SDK, since its a new field for me..(as it is an academic project) can anyone tell..me how to start with my application, like which libraries can be helpful and..how the application should work like...whether a user should first mark the audio file listen to it and then stop it at checkpoint and add the audio file to the new audio files ..This is what I was thinking of doing it...is my approach right??..

I would be very much thankful to your guidance.

Comment: This question is overly broad, asking separate, more focused, questions (e.g. one for choosing the library, one for the UI approach, ...) would work better here.

Comment: thanks...first i will try to work on the functionality..than I'll loook for the UI part...

Answer (score 0):

There is a WWDC video called Audio Development for iPhone OS available if you are a registered apple developer on developer.apple.com.
Some of the frameworks used for this sort of thing are AudioToolbox AudioUnit and AVFoundation. AudioUnit is shown in this video as being specifically for mixing. I am no expert but hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you so much...I will go through the AudioToolbox framework for a headstart...I will post more questions..based on my further research...on this thread.